# Problems formatting in HTML

Tags: html, css

The `headertext` font size changes but it won't be centered. Only just started learning HTML so this is likely a rookie mistake. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

```css
.main {
  margin-left: 220px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  margin-top: 20px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
}
    
.main headertext {
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">  
  <headertext>ExampleTitle</headertext>
  <p>Welcome to my website.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a minor comment, there is no as such headertext html element or tag. Change it to p tag. If your intent is to centre the text create a div and assign class headertext to it. My suggestion https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp is really good for html and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`headertext` is not a valid HTML element. Change it to a `div` with a class of `headertext` and I think that fixes your issue, snippet below:

```css
.main {
    margin-left: 220px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.main .headertext {
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">      
        <div class="headertext"> ExampleTitle </div>
        <p> Welcome to my website.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is there is no `<headertext>` element. You need to use `<h1>` (biggest) to `<h6>` (smallest). If you want it centered, use the following CSS:

```
h1 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you want to it to act as a title (semantically) you should probably give it a h1 tag instead. Like so

```css
.main {
    margin-left: 220px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">      
        <h1> ExampleTitle </h1>
        <p> Welcome to my website.</p>
</div>
```

This will tell the browser and people who use screenreaders that it's actually a title. You may benefit from reading up on html tags. This is a useful link and whilst it may seem overwhelming, you'll get used to it pretty quickly. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_byfunc.asp

Answer (score 1):

There is no element called `headertext`. Instead you can user `header` which is whole wrapper in standard or `h1`/`h2`/`h3`/`h4`/`h5`/`h6` which are commonly used to represent headings.

In your code if you want to follow the first heading you can follow the following code:

```css
.main {
    margin-left: 220px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.header-text {
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">      
        <h1 class="header-text"> ExampleTitle </h1>
        <p> Welcome to my website.</p>
</div>
```

But it seems in-align with other contents. I guess you are looking for the following.

```css
.main {
  /*margin-left: 220px;*/ //remove this line
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center; //added this line
}

.header-text {
  font-size: 45px;
  /* text-align: center; */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1 class="header-text"> ExampleTitle </h1>
  <p> Welcome to my website.</p>
</div>
```

I added both way that you can try for now. But still there is many ways to give you a solution. Happy journey on **HTML,CSS**